# CSS - styles Color not taking for anchor tag when using elipsis but taking same color which is using for main div class

Tags: html, css

> NOTE : **CSS Color not taking for anchor tag when using elipsis but
>   taking same color which is using for main div class**

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO HERE :](http://jsfiddle.net/WfBKe/)**

**CSS :**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .oneline {
        text-overflow : ellipsis;
        white-space   : nowrap;
        width         : 50px;
        overflow      : hidden;
        color: #f00;
     }
    a {color:#000;}
</style>
<div class="oneline">

    Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789 <br/>
    <a href="">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an extra element around text. Since you have given it to parent element it consider the ellipsis color as paretnt element text color.

**HTML**

```
<div class="oneline">    
    <span>Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789</span> <br/>
    <a href="">Testing 123 Testing 456 Testing 789</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.oneline span, .oneline a {
        display:block;
        text-overflow : ellipsis;
        white-space   : nowrap;
        width         : 50px;
        overflow      : hidden;
        color:#f00;
     }  
    .oneline a {       
        color:#000
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OtoZIQOy/6/)**

Comment: without giving important i added the color :-)

Comment: Yeah u dnt need importance. That I had used when I was trying with your html then I forgot to remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.oneline,.oneline a{color: #f00;}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WfBKe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have set color black for all elements with 'a' tag.

To give a specific color to a specific element 'a' tag, use classname with 'a' tag and specify the color you want.